# Displaying values that were removed from list

Tags: c#, list, removeall

Hello I'm currently removing elements from list doing this:

```
candidateList.RemoveAll(x => versionslist.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name && y.Parent.Name == x.Parent.Name));
```

I want to see what is actually being removed so i can compare it after with versionList to see why not all the values are being removed. I know this because version list is a sublist of canadidateList and after the removeall the math doesnt add up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way to see what items are removed from list.

If you need it for debugging - one easy way would be to just use `.Where(...).ToList()` with the same condition before call to `.RemoveAll` and inspect the result.

If you need that information at run-time consider using [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of regular list and listen to "removed" notifications.

Comment: can i then get the elements that were different ?

Comment: rnadom question does removeall remove duplicates as well so something that fits the predicate exsits more than once the exact same one

Answer (score 2):

Before you RemoveAll do:

```
var removedList = candidateList.Where(x => versionslist.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name && y.Parent.Name == x.Parent.Name));
```

Now you have the list of what will be removed, then perform the remove all:

```
candidateList.RemoveAll(x => versionslist.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name && y.Parent.Name == x.Parent.Name));
```

Comment: can i then get the elements that were different ?